# Error when running db.create_all() in SQLALChemy in Flask using PostgresSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to use SQLAlchemy to create a table in a Database in an flask application. However I am getting an error and I am unable to resolve it.
Can you please help me to resolve it ?
I am totally new to this as I just enrolled in the Udacity web development nanodegree and this is what I have to do there.

My code -

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/DB#'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable = False)


db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello the free world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Error -

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/kinjalk/Demo_scripts/app.py
/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/kinjalk/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

And I am getting very long error like this which I am not able to post here as StackOverflow is not allowing it.

Comment: It says you didn't supply a password.

Comment: If postgres is serving from a Unix domain socket (likely on a linux machine), try omitting the host and auth details:  `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///DB#'`